# create this table using my sql

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a movie database. Please help me to create a table containing the following columns:

movieid,title,language,actor,actress,image

In the field image I have to store the image of the movies. Please give example I have problem with image field.

My platform is Ubuntu. I'm creating this database for just to display like in YouTube. I'm directly inserting the values in MySQL not using any tool for it.

Please be clear with image part how to store.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: This might help http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All code provided in PHP/MySQL.

First of all, let's create the table within which our data will go.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movies` (
  `movieid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `language` text NOT NULL,
  `actor` text NOT NULL,
  `actress` text NOT NULL,
  `image` blob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`movieid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

In order to store images in a MySQL table you must read the data into a variable and escape it accordingly.

```
// $pathToFile = path to the image file you wish to store as BLOB
$data = msyql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($pathToFile));
```

Next, we can insert an entry into our table using the following query.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO movies SET
    title='New Movie',
    language='English',
    actor='John Doe',
    actress='Jane Doe',
    image='$data'");
```

That should result in a row containing the information relating to the film, and a BLOB field containing the image data taken from the file at the path stored in the $pathToFile variable.

Comment: Of course - in reality you'd escape all the other columns being inserted, not just the image column.

Comment: pls tell me wre shoul i type the codes // $pathToFile = path to the image file you wish to store as BLOB
$data = msyql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($pathToFile));

Comment: This should be ran as a PHP script - there is more involved than just using that one line though. You need to first of all retrieve the path of the image (either via an upload FORM, or a pre-determined path). You'd also need to connect to your database to be able to perform the query. Do you have any experience with PHP?

Comment: No im new to field. im just student working in company as inter for project. im working on vod. i have to submit a sample using qt4

Comment: In that case I'd suggest reading up on PHP or another scripting language to achieve this. I'm not familiar with QT4 - is it a platform specific library/tool, or simply another kind of management console? Can you provide a link to the software?

Comment: On the subject of QT4 - check out this thread here: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/24261-how-to-save-a-image-file-%28-say-png-%29-into-mysql-database

It describes how to convert an image into a BYTE ARRAY which could then be inserted into a BLOB field using a base64 representation of the result of the data() method.

Comment: i have no idea about link it was download from ubuntu software manager

Comment: In that case - I'd recommend Navicat. It's a very good database management tool available for Windows, Mac and Linux and should allow you to insert a row into the above described database with data from a file. See the two URLs below for download and reference to inserting a row with BLOB data.

http://navicat.com/en/download/download.html
http://wiki.navicat.com/wiki/index.php/How_do_I_insert_pictures_into_my_table%3F

Answer (score 0):

http://www.phpriot.com/articles/storing-images-in-mysql

And, you better use a tool like phpMyAdmin.
If you are using ubuntu, that can be installed from software manager

Comment: i'm using qt4 to display the database, i just want to insert it directly

Comment: I suggested phpMyAdmin is only for testing during development. For tasks such as, to verity whether data is being inserted, deleted from your appliation etc.. not to be used from your application and not for distribution :)